# RecylerView Add On Scroll not called inside Swipe to refresh layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listener

I have put Recyclerview inside Swipe to Refresh layout. Swipe to refresh code working. While for Endless recylerview added add on scroll listener on recylerview. Add on scroll listener never been called.

**main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/WhiteOpacity">
      <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/rcv_home_screen"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
          android:scrollbars="vertical"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
      </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Listener Add OnScroll**

```
 recylerview.addOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (dy > 0) {
                 Log.d("test", "working);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please put the code of your `SwipeRefreshLayout` also. where you are managing the case that when `RecyclerView` Scroll is working you have to disable the `SwipeRefreshLayout` and vice versa for enabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code. Scroll listener works even if your `RecyclerView` is nested inside a `SwipeRefreshLayout`

**Step1:** Set layout manager to your recyclerview.

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recylerview.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

**Step 2:** Implement a custom scroll listener by extending `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`

```
public abstract class EndlessScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener{
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int currentPage = 0;
    private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
    private boolean loading = true;
    private int startingPageIndex = 0;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    public EndlessScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(GridLayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
        visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold * layoutManager.getSpanCount();
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
        visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold * layoutManager.getSpanCount();
    }

    public int getLastVisibleItem(int[] lastVisibleItemPositions) {
        int maxSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lastVisibleItemPositions.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            }
            else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            }
        }
        return maxSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView view, int dx, int dy) {
        int lastVisibleItemPosition = 0;
        int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();

        if (mLayoutManager instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
            int[] lastVisibleItemPositions = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPositions(null);
            lastVisibleItemPosition = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions);
        } else if (mLayoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager) {
            lastVisibleItemPosition = ((GridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        } else if (mLayoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
            lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        }

        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
            this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
            this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            if (totalItemCount == 0) {
                this.loading = true;
            }
        }

        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        }

        if (!loading && (lastVisibleItemPosition + visibleThreshold) > totalItemCount) {
            currentPage++;
            onLoadMore(currentPage, totalItemCount, view);
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    public void resetState() {
        this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
        this.previousTotalItemCount = 0;
        this.loading = true;
    }

    public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view);
}
```

**Step 3:** Add scroll listener to your `recyclerview`

```
recylerview.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        }
});
```

Comment: onLoadMore or onScrolled never been called.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [addOnScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView#addOnScrollListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnScrollListener)) specific to RecyclerView

Comment: Its specific to recyclerview.